# storing values from csv file to the attributes of a class

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to code for a scheduling problem. Today I've got a problem in my code. I am trying to store the values from a csv file to the attributes of a class. please help me to understand it.

```
import math
import csv

from math import radians, sin, cos, acos

class masterTrainer:        #class generated for the master trainers for the whole state
    with open("mtData.csv", "r") as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
        for row in csv_input:
            masterTrainer.name = row['Name']
            masterTrainer.location = row['Location']
            masterTrainer.subject = row['Subject']
            masterTrainer.latitude = row['latitude']
            masterTrainer.longitude = row['longitude']

    def distanceCalculator(latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2):
        slat = radians(latitude1)
        slon = radians(longitude1)
        elat = radians(latitude2)
        elon = radians(longitude2)
        dist = 6371.01 * acos(sin(slat)*sin(elat) + cos(slat)*cos(elat)*cos(slon - elon))
        print("The distance is %.2fkm." % dist)

class venue:
    with open("venueData.csv", "r") as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
        for row in csv_input:
            venue.name = row['Name']
            venue.latitude = row['latitude']
            venue.longitude = row['longitude']

print(masterTrainer.distanceCalculator(float(masterTrainer.latitude),float(masterTrainer.longitude),float(venue.latitude),float(venue.longitude)),masterTrainer.name, venue.name)
```

The above code is showing an attribute error.

```
AttributeError: type object 'masterTrainer' has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a class in python, and want to store values on some member of this class, the proper way to do it is like:

```
class NameOfClass:
    def __init__(self, something, ...): #of course change "..." to the rest of arguments
        self.someAttribute = something
```

So, first define a method called `__init_\_(self, ...):` and put your `with open(....) as ...:` inside of it, and change all the `masterTrainer.whatever` to `self.whatever` inside it.